# dispatch_async task problems with context

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using a `dispatch_async` task to retrieve a list with some contacts.
When selecting a contact from this list, I call Storage Manager to retrive some further information for this contact.
I get the error: ***Illegal attempt to establish a relationship***...between objects in different contexts.
How to solve this?
Here is my code:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
      sections = [self getContactList];
   });

informationList = [StorageManager getInfoForContact:[sections objectAtIndex:1]];
```

The error is at the line with informationList. Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: Read Core Data Concurrency guide at least three times, then establish a new context in the block and make sure changes after saving are propagated to your main context. also note that you should use objectIDs when passing objects between contexts.

Comment: I hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the whole picture of your problem. However you are calling `[self getContactList]` into a async block. So, while `[self getContactList]` is executing the next line outside the block will be called. That means:

```
informationList = [StorageManager getInfoForContact:[sections objectAtIndex:1]];
```

is executed before:

```
sections = [self getContactList];
```

Probably your error is there.

Try:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    sections = [self getContactList];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        informationList = [StorageManager getInfoForContact:[sections objectAtIndex:1]];
    });
});
```